# Where to find the flat icons, avatars and graphics used in Topeka demo Android app?

Tags: android, image, graphics, icons

Where can I find the art assets used in the Topeka demo Android app as shown in the below figure? [Here is an article discussing same.](https://divshot.com/blog/web-components/exploring-googles-material-design-with-polymer/)

[Here is the Github.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka)

[image: Topeka Demo App]

Comment: @Dor: [Thank you for pointing me there.](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/tree/master/base/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi) That actually helps. However, I was wondering, and I guess I should have been more specific, but is there any larger collection of assets in that style that those images are pulled from? A "project" of some kind, perhaps? They seem very compatible with the Material Design framework and styling system.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that what you wanted but all the icons can be found at the [res dir](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/tree/master/base/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi) of the Github project you posted

Comment: Thank you. That actually helps. However, I was wondering, and I guess I should have been more specific, but is there any larger collection of assets in that style that those images are pulled from? A "project" of some kind, perhaps? They seem very compatible with the Material Design framework and styling system.